# how to add a list of JSON values into keys with JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have an input file:

```
{
  "errands": [
    {
      "name": "broker-deregistrar",
      "label": "Deregister and Purge Instances",
      "impact_warning": null,
      "pre_delete": true
    },
    {
      "name": "delete-all-service-instances",
      "label": "Delete All Service Instances",
      "impact_warning": null,
      "pre_delete": true
    },
    {
      "name": "deregister-broker",
      "label": "Deregister On-Demand Service Broker",
      "impact_warning": null,
      "pre_delete": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to reformat this to make the values of `.name` into a key with a fixed value like this:

```
{
"deploy_products": "all",
"errands": {
    "product_1_guid": {
      "run_pre_delete": {
        "broker-deregistrar": true,
        "delete-all-service-instances": true,
        "deregister-broker": true
      }
    }
  },
  "ignore_warnings": true
}
```

I can subset the values I want with this filter:

```
.errands[].name
```

which gives me:

```
"broker-deregistrar"
"delete-all-service-instances"
"deregister-broker"
```

but I want to get the selected values into a new JSON as keys.

while this kind of works,

```
.errands=(.product_1_guid=(.run_pre_delete=(.xxx=true | .yyy=true | .zzz=true)))
```

the list of errand names is variable in that they have different names and counts. i.e. the list of errands may only be "delete-apps", or even nothing at all.

and in the above example I need `.xxx`, `.yyy` and `.zzz` to come from the original JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the name-true pairs within an array constructor so that you can easily merge them with `add` and place the result wherever it belongs.

```
{
  deploy_products: "all",
  errands: {
    product_1_guid: {
      run_pre_delete: [
        { (.errands[].name): true }
      ] | add
    }
  },
  ignore_warnings: true
}
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1FkiBpT3Qf)</sup>